# Не могу убрать системную рамку окна в PyQT6

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt6, framelesswindowhint, windowflags

```py
class Widget(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Jarvis):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowType.FramelessWindowHint)
```

Answer (score 1):

*PyQt6* изменил способ работы с флагами и перечислениями,
теперь они доступны через имена флагов. 
Попробуйте использовать `Qt.WindowFlags.FramelessWindowHint`.

```
self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowFlags.FramelessWindowHint)
```

Answer (score 1):

Была аналогичная проблема, сам не до конца разобрался почему (учусь еще), но помогло так:

```
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt
...
self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowType.FramelessWindowHint)
```

Comment: Поясните, пожалуйста, чем ваш ответ отличается от ранее данных?

Comment: я обратил внимание на то, что сам код установки типа окна верен для PyQt6, ошибка скорее всего была в синтаксисе при подключении модуля. Ну и мне кажется для решения данного вопроса все таки лучше подключить класс Qt, а не весь модуль QtCore

Answer (score 0):

В PyQT6 работает вот так теперь

```
self.setWindowFlag(QtCore.Qt.WindowType.FramelessWindowHint)
```